# AutoPostBack conflict with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, autopostback

I want to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/PFNAe/3/) but in asp.net.  How would I write this in asp.net/the code behind?  I already have

```
protected void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkBox.Checked){}
    else{}
}
```

with

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="chkBox" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"
      onCheckedChanged="chkBox_CheckedChanged" />
```

so I need help filling in the rest.  Seriously though, thanks so much!

**UPDATE 2:**
This method works but the message/div doesn't show long enough to read the text.  Found out it's due to `AutoPostBack="true"`.  How do I call the event after the AutoPostBack is done (I'm guessing that's what I need to solve the problem)?

```
function displayDiv(checkbox) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                $("#message1").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(10000);
                $("#message2").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#message1").stop(true, true).hide();
                $("#message2").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(10000);
            }
        }


<asp:CheckBox ID="chkNotifyMe" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"   OnCheckedChanged="chkNotifyMe_CheckedChanged" onclick="displayDiv(this)" /> 
<div id="message1" class="message" ><span>Successfully <small></small></span></div><br />
<div id="message2" class="message" ><span>Removed<small></small></span></div>
```

(all css is the same)

So close I can taste it :D  Thanks again!

**FINAL SOLUTION**
Alright I added this to my page to call the AutoPostBack through jQuery and after it posts, to display my message

```
function pageLoad() {
            <%# autoLaunchJS %>
             $("#chkNotifyMe").click(chkNotifyMe_clicked);
        }
function chkNotifyMe_clicked(){
    var add = $get("chkNotifyMe").checked == true;
    PageMethods.WishList(add, <%#ID%>, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    }

    function OnSucceeded(){
        refreshStartPage();
        if($get("chkNotifyMe").checked){
                    $("#messageSuccess").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(5000);
                    $("#messageRemove").hide();
        }
        else{
            $("#messageSuccess").stop(true, true).hide();
            $("#messageRemove").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I ended up changing around a couple of divs to solve my autopostback problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have client code and server logic at the same time for a server control. If the display of that div is all you are planning to do, then it's pure view logic and it definitely something to do with javascript and posting back to server and refreshing the view would be wasteful.

You can slightly change your javascript to do this

```
function displayDiv(checkBox) {
        if (checkBox.checked) {
                            $("#message1").stop(true,true).show().fadeOut(4000);
            $("#message2").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#message1").stop(true,true).hide();
            $("#message2").stop(true,true).show().fadeOut(4000);
        }

    }
```

and

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="chkBox" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"
      onCheckedChanged="chkBox_CheckedChanged" onclick="displayDiv(this)" />
```

Comment: @ComatoesDuck In your second method, you have everything right but one thing. `onclick="displayDiv(checked)"` should be `onclick="displayDiv(this)"` .

Comment: that definitely made it appear.  Now the problem is that the messages don't show for long enough.  I tried `.show(4000)` but then nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

Create a label with that css

```
<asp:Label id="lblChkchnged" runat="server" CssClass="message" Visible="False" />
```

and then set in your check changed event the code

```
lblChkchnged.visible = true;
lblChkchnged.text = chkBoc.Checked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked";
```

Though really why not just leave it as a client call unless you need to do more than that?

Comment: I would love to leave it as a client call and I tried it but it didn't work